# How to multiply user input in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

i want to create simple view that takes user input(a number) and renders on other page this number multiplied by 2.

my code:

views.py

```
def multiply(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get("decimalfield")
        twice = data * 2
        return render(request, 'multiply.html', twice)
```

input.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'input' %}">
    <input type="text" name="decimalfield">
    <button type="submit">Upload text</button>
</form>
```

My problem is this is not working, now i get error: 
The view .views.multiply didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

My second problem is i don't know how to render that result on second page, not on this same.
Should urls look another like mine?

urls.py

```
path('input', views.multiply, name='input'),
path('multiply', views.multiply, name='multiply'),
```

I am really dejected because this is so simple and i am not able to do it.

Comment: Are you sure that your request method is really post method? I think it is not and it cannot render any page and gives error.Could you check it?

Comment: If you mean informations on error website i got: GET
No GET data
No POST data. What should i change?

Answer (score 2):

What i found to work for me:

views.py :

```
def input(request):
    return render(request, 'input.html', {})

def multiply(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get("decimalfield")
        twice = int(data) * 2
        return render(request, 'multiply.html', {'twice':twice})
```

urls.py :

```
path('input', views.input, name='input'),
path('multiply', views.multiply, name='multiply'),
```

input.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'multiply' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="decimalfield">
    <button type="submit">Upload text</button>
</form>
```

multiply.html

```
<label>{{ twice }}</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

parameters should be dictionary. views.py:

```
def multiply(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get("decimalfield")
        twice = data * 2
        return render(request, 'multiply.html', {'twice':twice})
    return render(request, 'input.html')
```

why do you have two urls pointing to one view? what is the second one? remove it

```
path('input', views.multiply, name='input'),
# path('multiply', views.multiply, name='multiply'),
```

create **multiply.html** and render **twice**:

```
<p>{{ twice }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i appreciate it :) I commented this second view and i also changed last line in my view. Unfortunately i still get this same error.

Comment: you are getting this error because you only checking for post method. post method occurs when you submit the form. but before you can even submit the form, you should render the form and that is method GET. i changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok because the first method when you get into the page throug url (name = 'input') is request so they dont retrun render beacause it inside method POST you can now edit:

```
def multiply(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST.get("decimalfield")
    twice = {'data':data*2 }
    return render(request, 'multiply.html', twice)
  return render(request, 'multiply.html')
```